# node_redis - No puedo retornar un valor desde el interior de una consulta

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Me estoy volviendo loco con un problema la que no le encuentro solución. No puedo retornar valores desde el interior de una consulta a Redis. Estoy utilizando el cliente de Redis para NodeJS node_redis (http://redis.js.org/).

El problema es el siguiente: Escribí una función para obtener el estado de conexión de un usuario y retornarlo para poder ser utilizado en otra función.

```
//CHECK USER STATUS
exports.checkUserStatus = function(uid){
    redis.multi()
        .sismember('users:online',uid)
        .sismember('users:iddle', uid)
        .sismember('users:out', uid)
        .sismember('users:locked', uid)
        .exec(function(err, res){
            res.forEach(function(res, index){
                if(res != 0){
                    switch(index){
                        case 0:
                            return 'online';
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            return 'iddle';
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            return 'out';
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            return 'locked';
                            break;
                        default:
                            return 'offline';
                    }
                }
            });
        })
}
```

Pero, la función no retorna nada!. Si reemplazo la lína del "return" por un "console.log()", funciona! pero, no necesito una salida en consola, necesito capturar el valor en una variable, en una función externa!

También intenté creando una variable dentro de la función pero, fuera de la consulta, llenarla dentro de la consulta y luego exportarla desde fuera de la consulta pero, no funciona.

Otra cosa que intenté hacer fue agregar la sentencia "return" al comenzar la consulta (algo que aparece en la documentación del driver), pero, siempre me devuelve TRUE, lo cual no es el valor de la consulta sino que terminó de ejecutarse.

Alguien sabe cómo hacer esto?

Saludos y gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conozco la librería, pero esto pasa por como funciona javascript (de forma asincronica para E/S). El asunto es que ese `return` no es el return de la función que estas exportando sino del callback interno (el de segundo nivel).

La forma tradicional de hacer esto en javascript es continuar con los callbacks o resolverlo usando [Promesas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promesa) (tema que no abordare, te recomiendo investigarlo pues ayuda a lidiar con el [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/)).

Esto funciona así: cuando la API de redis obtiene la respuesta, se invoca una función del usuario donde se termina de procesar los datos.

La funcion modificada: (con comentarios)

```
//CHECK USER STATUS ... fijate que agregue un parametro, la funcion del usuario
exports.checkUserStatus = function(uid, callback){
    redis.multi()
        .sismember('users:online',uid)
        .sismember('users:iddle', uid)
        .sismember('users:out', uid)
        .sismember('users:locked', uid)
        .exec(function(err, res){
            res.forEach(function(res, index){
                if(res != 0){
                    switch(index){
                        case 0:
                            // aqui invocas la funcion del usuario
                            // y le pasas todos los datos que puedan ser utiles
                            callback('online', res, index); 
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            callback('iddle', res, index); 
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            callback('out', res, index); 
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            callback('locked', res, index); 
                            break;
                        default:
                            callback('offline', res, index); 
                    }
                }
            });
        })
}
```

Luego lo usas de esta forma:

```
// de paso comentare la secuencia de eventos
// esto sucede #1
checkUserStatus('uid-12343', function(status, user) {
    // esto sucede #3, en el futuro proximo... 
    // aqui tienes el resultado ... de forma asincronica.
});

// esto sucede #2
console.log("esto pasa antes de que llegue la respuesta de REDIS");
```

Ten en cuenta que este metodo esta muy simplificado para que entiendas el problema y como abordar la solucion pues en NodeJs lo tienes que usar constantemente y es fundamental entenderlo.

Cuidado! Ten en cuenta que `callback` podría ser invocado mas de una vez ya que todo esto se encuentra dentro de un `forEach`, del cual no se cual es el motivo ni su función pero no importa para que entiendas como funciona la cosa.

De todo esto, puedes sacar en limpio, que no hay forma de que una función asincronica pueda devolver una respuesta de forma sincronica. O usas callbacks, o usas promesas.

Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias! Me salvaste el día, estuve estancado acá toda la tarde! Todavía estoy acostumbrándome a esto de los callbacks y hay cosas que, por lo que veo, me funcionaban de casualidad jaja. Ahora lo entiendo mucho mejor, gracias de nuevo!